# Eclipse 2020-09 nodeclipse font size

Tags: node.js, eclipse, nodeclipse

I'm starting to work with nodejs.  I have nodeclipse installed on my Eclipse 2020-09 IDE.  The most infuriating thing is that the font size for the code editor windows is small.

I tried the Preferences->Colors and Fonts->Text Font (and all the other fonts), but this only seems to work on the CDT and JDT editors.  Anyone know how to adjust it on the nodeClipse JavaScript editor?

I am now working with C++, Java, Python and JavaScript/NodeJS.  Not finding any IDE that seems to do all these well.

Comment: Which download/installation of the IDE did you choose? Perhaps it's one that has JavaScript features provided through opening files in the Generic Text Editor. Alternately, does nodeclipse have a Text font entry of its own?

Comment: I had added nodeClipse to my PHP and Java version of 2020-09, but those had problems with the font size.  I have now downloaded and installed the Javascript version of Eclipse.  That has better fonts, but it's missing some of the more useful editor features like Ctrl-Shift-P which sends you to the matching brace. Thanks.